# --disable-host-check vs --disableHostCheck

Tags: angular

Bellow is output of `ng --version`. If I understand correctly then my version of Angular is 5.2.2, if I'm wrong correct me please:

```
c:\Users\wakatana\Documents\coding\my-angular-app>ng --version
Your global Angular CLI version (6.2.4) is greater than your local
version (1.6.6). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.6.6
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.1.1
@angular/cli: 1.6.6
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/material: 5.1.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.6
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

I need to debug some CORS related problems. So I would like to start my app with disable host check. My app stars with any of following commands:

```
ng serve --app my-angular-app --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
ng serve --app my-angular-app --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check=true
ng serve --app my-angular-app --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check true
ng serve --app my-angular-app --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck
ng serve --app my-angular-app --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck=true
ng serve --app my-angular-app --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true
```

This is suspicious to me and I do not know if disable host check has any affect. I bet that I've read somewhere in the past that `disableHostCheck` and `disable-host-check` should serve for different versions of angular. But I cannot find it in any documentation. Which one should I use in my case, or does it even mater? Where is this documented? Thanks

Comment: [Found this might be helpful](https://help.crossbrowsertesting.com/faqs/testing/invalid-host-header-error/)